# Ionic 2 - Json storage in LocalStorage or in the App

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, get, storage

I'm creating an app, for IOS/Android.
In this app i have a list of objects(Img, Name etc...), store in a backend server(node.js).

I want to display/remove/add/modify this list from the app and everybody with the app too. I can get all of them with Json request.
And my question is what is the best, store the json request in LocalStorage or
Store it in a variable(Array) when the app is launch.

Or maybe just store image i don't know.

My Object:

```
object:
{
    name: String;
    ingred: Array;
    img: String;
}
```

Thanks you.

Comment: you can store it inside the app's storage and then use socket.io to help check if a particular item is removed so it updates online and sends it to the other devices that are tied to it, so they receive the event and update their list with a refresh or something

Comment: yes, i thought about cache storage too.. i really don't know what can be the best to do..

Answer (score 0):

So, i think i will store everything in local, and use socket.io or something for synchronize data.